# Execute system commands in parallel in different directories

Tags: c++, multithreading, system, c++98

I have an executable reading and writing data files in the local directory. I want to execute it from C++ (without C++11) in (for example) 2 directories `run1` and `run2` with different input files. For the moment, I do it sequentially by this way :

```
boost::filesystem::path dir1("/path/to/my/workdir/run1");
boost::filesystem::path dir2("/path/to/my/workdir/run2");
boost::filesystem::current_path(dir1);
std::ofstream f1("data.txt");
f1 << 1.0 << " " << 2.0 << std::endl;
f1.close();
system("/path/to/the/executable");
std::ifstream r1("results.txt");
r1 >> x1;
boost::filesystem::current_path(dir2);
std::ofstream f2("data.txt");
f2 << 7.0 << " " << 3.0 << std::endl;
f2.close();
system("/path/to/the/executable");
std::ifstream r2("results.txt");
r2 >> x2;
```

I want to run it in two threads, but I saw that `boost::filesystem::current_path` change the directory for all the threads. Then I have no idea how to do that properly...

Comment: Is there a reason why /path/to/my/executable must read and write files in cwd rather than being told the full paths to its input and output files?

Comment: It's the expected and actual behaviour of the application, and it can't be changed. :/

Comment: Ah. The "my" in the path gave me the mistaken impression that you have some control over how the executable works. Maybe you should fork separate processes rather than trying to parallelize this on threads in one process.

Comment: A fork duplicates the memory, no ? If it's the case it's not a solution because, in my real case, my application is really huge in memory (Gigabytes) and I sometimes have to run more than 100 executables in parallel.

Comment: You could fork off the extra processes before allocating all that memory. All those processes have to do is each change to a different directory and call the system command to run the other executable. You may need some socket communication to get them to do this at the right time. Thinking about this further, it might even make more sense to start multiple processes from a script: several "worker" processes that run the other executable, and one process that coordinates the workers and does everything else.